# Model from com.avaje.ebean is not compatible

Tags: java, ebean, playframework-2.4

I've been using 2.3 for a while now and due to some performance with Ebean I decided to switch to a newer version.

Now, I've found out that I can no longer use orphanRemoval method.

I've also noticed that query caches started working and my application turned buggy, EAGER loading also started working (everything was lazy before) but I've somehow figured out how to bypass the ConcurrentModificationErrors.

**What is an alternative to orphanRemoval?**

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I've found out that I can no longer use orphanRemoval metho

d.

**orphanRemoval** has not been removed. You will need to be more specific as to what your issue is.

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/issues/45 this seems to indicated that switch to ebean removes the orphanRemoval, and that's exactly what I did. I get a compile time error about orphanRemoval being an unknown method. It looks to me as if play supported orphanRemoval but ebean doesn't.

Comment: That ticket is not accurate (Well, it is wrong). Ebean has had orphanRemoval prior to it being called 'orphanRemoval' and it is called PrivateOwned

Comment: I have updated the ticket you linked to - hopefully that makes it a little clearer.  Again, in Ebean this predates JPA2 and hence is called @PrivateOwned (as it was called in Hibernate) and Ebean has had this feature for a long time and no it hasn't been removed.

Comment: So what is the actual answer here? Should we remove `orphanRemoval` and add `@PrivateOwned` along with the `@OneToMany`?

Comment: Yes Anton, use `@PrivateOwned`.